# Symfony 1.4 Propel: Accessing Table Data via Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, propel

I need data from two MySQL tables - I wrote a Propel query to retrieve data from my 'search' table. Now, I am trying to retrieve data from my 'item_view' table using `->getItemView()->getPosition()` within the view. The search_id (search table primary key) is a foreign key in the item_view table but the item_view_id (item view primary key) is not a foreign key in the search table. Any suggestions for how to retrieve this data? Code below.

**View:**

```
<?php foreach ($queries as $query) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $query->getTs(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getUser() ? $query->getUser()->getEmail() : ""; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getTerm(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getResultCount(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo **$query->getItemViews()->getItem()->getPartName()**; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo **$query->getItemViews()->getPosition()**; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Controller:** (note: I have no problem retrieving user table data because its foreign key is in the search table.

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(SearchPeer::TS);
$this->queries = SearchPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Is this a case where you cannot retrieve data from a table unless its primary key is the foreign key of the table for which the propel query is formed?

Any solutions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem, which had less to do with Propel and Symfony and everything to do with my understanding of relational databases.

There may be **multiple** item_view rows for a single search row. The `->getItemView()` I was trying to originally use should be `->getItemViews()` because there is a one to many relationship. It also needs to be nested as its own foreach loop to retrieve values. Correct code below:

**View:**

```
<?php foreach ($queries as $query) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $query->getTs(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getUser() ? $query->getUser()->getEmail() : ""; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getTerm(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $query->getResultCount(); ?></td>
    <?php foreach ($query->getItemViews() as $iav) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $iav->getItem()->getPartName(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $iav->getPosition(); ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```